# Watching for an NSOperation to complete

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsoperationqueue

I am using an `NSOperationQueue` to get some data for my app:

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
GetSUPDataOperation *operation = [[GetDataOperation alloc] init];
operation.context = self;
[queue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];
```

I want to prevent the user from navigating to certain parts of the app until we have finished getting all the data we need.

Is there some way I can watch for the operation to finish and set a flag then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a delegate for the operation

```
@interface YourOperation : NSOperation  {
    id target;
    SEL selector;
}

- (id)initWithTarget:(id)theTarget action:(SEL)action;

@end
```

At the end of your operation (ie. inside main function), use

```
- (void)main  {
    Your code here...
    ...

    [target performSelectorOnMainThread:selector withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
 }
```

to ask your delegate to set a flag

Comment: So inside my GetDataOperation alloc method I should use add the performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
and it is smart enough to know what its finished and call a new method back on my main thread?

Comment: You should invoke this method at the end of the main function inside the operation.

Answer (score 0):

From an architectural point of view you don't want to "monitor" an operation for its running state. You'd want to invoke a method when an operation has finished running.

So just invoke a method that updates the UI (or some other part of the application) when the operation finished.